# Nginx controller not functioning and no new logs after a period of inactivity

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster where both the cluster itself and the pod/ingress controller are working properly. However, I'm encountering an issue where, after a period of inactivity (around a day) without using the cluster, the Nginx controller stops functioning and no new logs are generated.

Previously, when the cluster was active, I could see logs like the following examples:

```
│ ingress-nginx-controller-7fcc694bd4-qp42d 192.168.137.67 - - [28/Jun/2023:14:29:23 +0000] "GET /v1/ws/1s/engineimages HTTP/1.1" 101 946 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0" 560 4.063 [longhorn │
│ system-longhorn-frontend-80[] [] 10.244.0.47:8000 0 4.062 101 c885e84c218c54f037bbaa367fa534c5                                                                                                                                           │
│ ingress-nginx-controller-7fcc694bd4-qp42d 192.168.137.67 - - [28/Jun/2023:14:29:23 +0000] "GET /v1/ws/1s/recurringjobs HTTP/1.1" 101 137 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0" 561 4.056 [longhor │
│ -system-longhorn-frontend-80[] [] 10.244.0.48:8000 0 4.057 101 9ff96175bd97747f6327b847876fe1e3
```

However, today I'm not seeing any new logs. I have ruled out memory as a potential problem since I have 215 GB of memory available, and the server is quite powerful.

Does anyone have any insights into why the Nginx controller may stop functioning after a period of inactivity and how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.